# How to initialize json data in knockout js

Tags: json, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am new bie on knockout js.i create a crud operation one page app in which you click on add field a form appear you add the data and click on add button it add the data and if you click on save button it show the data in json format but when i am clicking on my save button i just want to save the data which is in form at that time not the whole data.i am able to do this functionality on click of delete but dont know how to perform on click of save here is whole structure

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="knockout-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table style="width:100%;" data-bind="visible:showFields">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width:100px;">Branch </th>
                    <th style="width:100px;">Enter Value</th>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Branch ID (int):</td>
                <td>
                    <input data-bind="value: BranchId" />
                    </td> <!--,valueUpdate:'keypress'-->
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name :</td>
                <td>
                    <input data-bind="value: Name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Description :</td>
                <td>
                    <input data-bind="value: Description" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Template :</td>
                <td>
                    <select data-bind="options: Templates, value: 
                    Template, optionsCaption: 'Select Template...'"></select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>MetaKeyword :</td>
                <td>
                    <input data-bind="value: MetaKeyword" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>MetaDescription :</td>
                <td>
                    <input data-bind="value: MetaDescription" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>MetaTitle :</td>
                <td>
                    <input data-bind="value: MetaTitle" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>EnableSearch :</td>
                <td>
                    <select data-bind="options: EnableSearchs, value: 
                    EnableSearch, optionsCaption: 'Select Search...'"></select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <button type="button" data-bind="click: 
                    AddBranch">Add Branch</button>
                    <button type="button" data-bind="click: 
                    SaveBranch">Save Branch</button>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
            </div>

         <div style="width:70%;float:left;display:inline-block;" data-bind="visible:show">
             <h2>List of Branches</h2>
        <table style="width:100%;" data-bind="visible: Branches().length > 0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <th>Branch Id</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Template</th>
                <th>MetaKeyword</th>
                <th>MetaDescription</th>
                <th>MetaTitle</th>
                <th>EnableSearch</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: Branches">
                <tr>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: BranchId" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <span data-bind="text: Name" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <span data-bind="text: Description" /></td>

                    <td>
                        <select data-bind="options: $root.Templates, 
                        value: Template"></select></td>
                    <td>
                        <span data-bind="text: MetaKeyword" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <span data-bind="text: MetaDescription" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <span data-bind="text: MetaTitle" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select data-bind="options: $root.EnableSearchs, 
                        value: EnableSearch"></select>
                    </td>

                    <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.
                    DeleteBranch">Delete</a></td>
                    <td><a href="#" data-bind="click:$root.edit">edit</a></td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
          <a href="#" data-bind="click:AddField">AddFields</a>

        </div>
</body>
<script>
function Branch(data) {
    this.BranchId = ko.observable(data.BranchId);
    this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
    this.Description = ko.observable(data.Description);
    this.Template = ko.observable(data.Template);
    this.MetaKeyword = ko.observable(data.MetaKeyword);
    this.MetaDescription = ko.observable(data.MetaDescription);
    this.MetaTitle = ko.observable(data.MetaTitle);
    this.EnableSearch = ko.observable(data.EnableSearch);
}

function BranchViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.EnableSearchs = ko.observableArray(['Yes', 'No']);
    self.Templates = ko.observableArray(['Template1', 'Template2']);
    self.Branches = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.BranchId = ko.observable();
    self.Name = ko.observable();
    self.Description = ko.observable();
    self.MetaKeyword = ko.observable();
    self.MetaDescription = ko.observable();
    self.MetaTitle = ko.observable();
    self.EnableSearch = ko.observable();
    self.Template = ko.observable();
    self.editBranch = ko.observable();
    self.show = ko.observable(true);
    self.showFields = ko.observable(false);
   self.flag = ko.observable(false);

    self.AddBranch = function () {
        if (self.flag()) {
            self.editBranch().BranchId(self.BranchId())
            self.editBranch().Name(self.Name())
            self.editBranch().Description(self.Description())
            self.editBranch().EnableSearch(self.EnableSearch())
            self.editBranch().MetaKeyword(self.MetaKeyword())
            self.editBranch().MetaDescription(self.MetaDescription())
            self.editBranch().MetaTitle(self.MetaTitle())
            self.editBranch().Template(self.Template())
            self.flag(false);
            self.show(true);
            self.showFields(false);
            self.BranchId(""),
             self.Name(""),
             self.Description(""),
             self.EnableSearch(""),
             self.MetaKeyword(""),
             self.MetaDescription(""),
             self.MetaTitle(""),
            self.Template("")
        }
    else{
        self.Branches.push(new Branch({
            BranchId: self.BranchId(),
            Name: self.Name(),
            Description: self.Description(),
            EnableSearch: self.EnableSearch(),
            MetaKeyword: self.MetaKeyword(),
            MetaDescription: self.MetaDescription(),
            MetaTitle: self.MetaTitle(),
            Template: self.Template()
        }));
         self.BranchId(""),
         self.Name(""),
         self.Description(""),
         self.EnableSearch(""),
         self.MetaKeyword(""),
         self.MetaDescription(""),
         self.MetaTitle(""),
        self.Template("")
        self.show(true);
        self.showFields(false);
        }
    };
    self.AddField = function(){
        self.show(false);
        self.showFields(true);


    }
    self.DeleteBranch = function (branch) {
        alert(ko.toJSON({ data: branch }));
    };


     self.edit = function (branch) { 
       self.editBranch(branch);
        self.show(false);
        self.showFields(true);
        self.BranchId(branch.BranchId());
        self.Name(branch.Name());
        self.Description(branch.Description());
        self.EnableSearch(branch.EnableSearch());
        self.MetaKeyword(branch.MetaKeyword());
        self.MetaDescription(branch.MetaDescription());
        self.MetaTitle(branch.MetaTitle());
        self.Template(branch.Template());
        self.flag(true);
    } 
    self.SaveBranch = function (branch) {
    alert(ko.toJSON( self.Branches));

    };


}

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new BranchViewModel());
});
</script>
</html>
```

secondly i want to display some json data on my page as my page get load. here is my json data.

```
[{"BranchId":"1","Name":"us","Description":"united states","Template":"Template1","MetaKeyword":"us","MetaDescription":"us","MetaTitle":"us","EnableSearch":"Yes"},{"BranchId":"2","Name":"europe","Description":"europe","Template":"Template1","MetaKeyword":"euro","MetaDescription":"euro","MetaTitle":"euro","EnableSearch":"Yes"},{"BranchId":"3","Name":"aus","Description":"aus","Template":"Template1","MetaKeyword":"aus","MetaDescription":"aus","MetaTitle":"aus","EnableSearch":"Yes"}]
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how can i initialize the json data on loading of page i post the json data and i want to show it on my fields as i open the page . secondly on click of save button i want to save the data which is in input fields only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you do it.. You need to convert each object from json to Branch. You can use computed for that.

Create new var for the JSON dataset

```
var dummyData = [{"BranchId":"1","Name":"us","Description":"united states","Template":"Template1","MetaKeyword":"us","MetaDescription":"us","MetaTitle":"us","EnableSearch":"Yes"},{"BranchId":"2","Name":"europe","Description":"europe","Template":"Template1","MetaKeyword":"euro","MetaDescription":"euro","MetaTitle":"euro","EnableSearch":"Yes"},{"BranchId":"3","Name":"aus","Description":"aus","Template":"Template1","MetaKeyword":"aus","MetaDescription":"aus","MetaTitle":"aus","EnableSearch":"Yes"}];

self.PopulateBranches = ko.computed(function(){
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(dummyData, function(item){
        self.Branches.push(new Branch(item));
    });
});
```

Here's updated JSFiddle for you : http://jsfiddle.net/x2ubuy44/

Comment: Hi Rahul, Do you have any idea how to save the data which is available in input fields when i click on save button

Comment: Updating answer. Just a min

Comment: It is same .there is no difference in it

Comment: in your solution now if i click on edit add the fields then it add the new field instead of editing the existing one

Comment: Well, I bound Add fields method which is in working state now :-)

Comment: Yes this is a problem i have to do CRUD operations in it. Thats why i need it. so that if some edit it so through json i update it in my repository. Do u find any solution for it ?

Comment: Updating jsfiddle :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59242/discussion-between-rahul-patil-and-user2142786).

Comment: i dont have access to chat. and still same problem arriving in jsfiddle when you edit a field and add it then it create a new field instead of editing it

Comment: Computed is overkill, you only need ko.utils.arrayMap since the array does not mutate

Comment: @Anders Array mapping is always a better option :-)

Comment: Updated Fiddle with ko.utils.arrayMap : http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/x2ubuy44/6/